# Using map::find to find a key and return the value

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary, iterator, find

My Goal is to look for a Key(objName) if it exist then return the value.

```
GameEntity * GameEntity::FindInContents(string objName)
{
   for( map<string, GameEntity*>:: iterator iter = contents.begin(); iter != contents.end(); iter++)
    {
       if(contents.find(objName)== contents.end())
           return (iter->second);
       else
           return NULL;
    }
}
```

However when i run the code it brings me to

```
/** There is also a templated copy ctor for the @c pair class itself.  */
#ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
  template<class _U1, class _U2>
pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
: first(__p.first), second(__p.second) { }
#else
```

I don't understand whats the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, i think you mean `contents.find(objName) != contents.end()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a loop as `find` returns an iterator to the found element or `end()` in case of no match.

So all you need is:

```
map<string, GameEntity*>:: iterator iter = contents.find(objName);
if(iter != contents.end())  // notice the !=
    return (iter->second);
else
    return NULL;
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find for details

Comment: It still jumps to the error above after i run the program. Does that mean there is an error somewhere else in my code. It opens a stl_pair.h file...

Comment: @Ares there probably is.

Comment: @Ares - yes, I also think you have a problem another place. See https://ideone.com/9M2Kny for a running example of the search code

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world are you using a for loop?

Try this:

```
decltype(auto) iter = contents.find(objName);
return iter != contents.end() ? iter : nullptr;
```

(Note: The `NULL` macro is deprecated, use `nullptr` instead.)

Comment: `decltype(auto)`? Did you mean to use just `auto`?

Comment: @RSahu nope, I prefer `decltype(auto)`, due to it giving reference types where `auto` wouldn't. (in this case I believe it would give `decltype(contents)::iterator&&`, wheras `auto` would give `decltype(contents)::iterator`). (note: I may be wrong, I currently do not have access to a compiler... to test it on)

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is wrong. The argument to `decltype` needs to be an expression.